# Adding Items to top of listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I have a code here that allows me to add items to the top. If I had 5 items,the way it would work is like this.

```
0 New Item 

1

2

3

4 First item
```

Then if something is new is added it becomes this.

```
0 New Item

1

2

3

4

5 First Item
```

As you can see,whenever a new item is added,it become position 0. This is a problem because if I set a checkbox on that's on position 0 and then a new item is added,the new item becomes position 0 which checks the new item and unchecks the item that was there before.
I want it to work like this while still add items to the top.

```
4 New item

3

2

1

0 First Item
```

When a new item is added.

```
5 New Item

4

3

2

1

0 First Item
```

Here is my ListView Adapter.

```
public class TweetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> implements OnClickListener {


    TweetList tweetMessageObj;
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    public List<TweetList> tweetList = new ArrayList<TweetList>();

    public void add(TweetList object,int position) {
        tweetList.add(position,object);

    }

    public TweetArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.tweetList.size();
    }

    public TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return tweetList.get(position);
    } 

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
            tweetMessageObj = getItem(position);

            if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.twitterUser = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            holder.tweet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.display_tweet);
            holder.twitterMention = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_twitter_mentionname);
            holder.profile_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            holder.tweet_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.tweet_image);
            holder.padding = (View)row.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            holder.favorite = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
            //holder.retweet = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.retweet_button);
            //holder.reply = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.reply_button);

            holder.favorite.setTag(holder);

             row.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }


            SpannableString hashtag = new SpannableString(tweetMessageObj.tweet);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            while (matcher.find())
            {
                hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            }
            while (matcher2.find())
            { hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
            }
            holder.tweet.setText(hashtag, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            holder.tweet.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.tweet.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweet.isEmpty()){
                holder.tweet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            holder.tweet.setTypeface(tf);
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
            holder.twitterUser.setText(tweetMessageObj.twittername);
            holder.twitterUser.setTypeface(tf2);
            holder.twitterMention.setText("@" + tweetMessageObj.mentionname);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.pictureURL).into(holder.profile_picture);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl != null){
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl).into(holder.tweet_picture);
            }else{
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        return row;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tweet,twitterUser,twitterMention;
    ImageView profile_picture,tweet_picture;
    CheckBox reply,retweet,favorite;
    View padding;
    boolean isFavorited = false;
}
```

**TweetList**

```
public class TweetList {
    public String twittername,mentionname,tweet,pictureURL,tweetPictureUrl;
    long status_id;



    public TweetList(long status_id,String twittername,String mentionname,String tweet,String pictureURL) {
        super();
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.twittername = twittername;
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
        this.mentionname = mentionname;


    }
    public TweetList(long status_id,String twittername,String mentionname,String tweet,String pictureURL,String tweetPictureUrl) {
        super();
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.twittername = twittername;
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
        this.mentionname = mentionname;
        this.tweetPictureUrl = tweetPictureUrl;


    }

}
```

Comment: post TweetList code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

**TweetList.java**

```
public class TweetList {
    public String twittername;
    public String mentionname;
    public String tweet;
    public String pictureURL;
    public String tweetPictureUrl;
    public long status_id;
    public boolean isFavourite;
    public TweetList(long status_id,String twittername,String mentionname,String tweet,String pictureURL,boolean isFavourite) {
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.twittername = twittername;
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
        this.mentionname = mentionname;
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
    }
    public TweetList(long status_id,String twittername,String mentionname,String tweet,String pictureURL,String tweetPictureUrl,boolean isFavourite) {
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.twittername = twittername;
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
        this.mentionname = mentionname;
        this.tweetPictureUrl = tweetPictureUrl;
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
    }
}
```

**TweetArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class TweetArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    public List<TweetList> tweetList;

    public void add(TweetList object,int position) {
        tweetList.add(position,object);

    }

    public TweetArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        tweetList = new ArrayList<TweetList>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.tweetList.size();
    }

    public TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return tweetList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.twitterUser = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            holder.tweet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.display_tweet);
            holder.twitterMention = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.display_twitter_mentionname);
            holder.profile_picture = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            holder.tweet_picture = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweet_image);
            holder.padding = (View)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            holder.favorite = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        SpannableString hashtag = new SpannableString(tweetList.get(position).tweet);
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
        Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                    String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context, tags, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                }
            },matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
        }
        while (matcher2.find())
        { hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
            hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                    String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context, tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                }
            },matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
        }
        holder.tweet.setText(hashtag, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        holder.tweet.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        holder.tweet.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if(tweetList.get(position).tweet.isEmpty()){
            holder.tweet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
        holder.tweet.setTypeface(tf);
        Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
        holder.twitterUser.setText(tweetList.get(position).twittername);
        holder.twitterUser.setTypeface(tf2);
        holder.twitterMention.setText("@" + tweetList.get(position).mentionname);

        Picasso.with(context).load(tweetList.get(position).pictureURL).into(holder.profile_picture);
        if(tweetList.get(position).tweetPictureUrl != null){
            holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.padding.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(tweetList.get(position).tweetPictureUrl).into(holder.tweet_picture);
        }else{
            holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.padding.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.favorite.setChecked(tweetList.get(position).isFavourite);

        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tweet,twitterUser,twitterMention;
        ImageView profile_picture,tweet_picture;
        CheckBox favorite;
        View padding;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's sort of working,whenever a new items gets added it unchecks all of them. Is this the correct way off adding items using this?

tweetAdapter.add(new TweetList(intent.getLongExtra("tweet_id",1),intent.getStringExtra("tweet_name"), intent.getStringExtra("tweet_screenname"), intent.getStringExtra("tweet"), intent.getStringExtra("tweet_profilepicture"),intent.getStringExtra("tweetPicture"),false),0);

Comment: It's also happening when I scroll through the list.

Comment: by default isFavourite is false so when you check checkbox also update value in particular tweetList item at position.

Comment: You are AWESOME! All week,I've been trying to figure out how to do this. You have made my day the best man.

Answer (score 1):

`isFavorited` is information that should be inside `TweetList`.
In this way in `getView` you can update the value of the `CheckBox`.

```
holder.favorite.setChecked(tweetMessageObj.isFavorited);
```